# Width property of form is not what it's set to, though looks OK

Tags: vb6, width

The form's borderstyle is "fixed single" so the user cannot alter the form's dimensions manually.

There is a menu item that allows the user to select 1 of 2 width settings for the form, choosing wide (width = 11715) displays extra controls.

During the load event a sub is called to set various values and which includes this code:

```
     If rs.Fields("ShowAll").Value = True then
        Me.Width = 11715
```

During the form unload event a sub is called to record the settings for the next time and which includes this code:

```
     If Me.Width = 11715 Then
        rs.Fields("ShowAll").Value = True
     Else
        rs.Fields("ShowAll").Value = False
     End If
```

One user has reported a situation where even though he always closes with the form "wide" it always opens "narrow".

I have never seen this happen before and nobody has ever reported it either, which is not to say it's not happening elsewhere.

His machine is windows 7 and his screen resolution is 1280 X 1024.

Edit :
Also when I checked his database the value for "ShowAll" is False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to hard-code the width then you have to choose a number of twips that is multiple of 15 for small-fonts and multiple of 12 for large-fonts. The least multiple of both is 60, so the closest to your hard-coded value is 11700 which is 780px in small-fonts and 975px in large-fonts exactly.

Mind that win7 comes with more DPI sizes besides 96 (aka "small-fonts") and 120 (aka "large-fonts"), which totally fail VB6 forms subsystem. So you are safe to assume that in VB6 pixel size is either 15 or 12 twips.

Comment: I think your answer is correct and I have learned something new thank you!. I reset my dpi to 120 dpi at the same resolution as the customer and I experienced the same phenomenon. Can you tell me if the vb6 ide 'forces' users to draw forms in widths that are a multiple of 15 as I never comsciously worked out that 11715 was a multiple of 15

Comment: The IDE aligns all sizes in twips (form's width/height, control's left/top) to multiples of 15 or 12 depending on the current dev machine font size, which might result in sub-pixel placements on client machines. Changing `ScaleMode` to pixels does not alleviate the problem and besides form's with and height are always in twips. `ScaleMode` affects contained controls left/top and form's scalewidth/scaleheight.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is ALL great information. For the benefit of people as ignorant as I was yesterday, if you have 96 dpi (dots/pixels per inch) then since there are 1440 twips per inch that means there are 1440/96 = 15 twips per dot/pixel.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a form level boolean variable rather than a specific number. You can also wrap it in a property if you like to make it easier to understand. Initialize the variable with the database value when you load your app and toggle the value when the button is clicked to choose the form size.

```
Private m_blnExpanded As Boolean

Private Property Let Expanded(ByVal vExpanded As Boolean)

       m_blnExpanded = vExpanded

End Property
Private Property Get Expanded() As Boolean

       Expanded = m_blnExpanded

End Property
```

Comment: Your way is the correct way to do it to avoid the difficulties I made for myself. However wqw explained to me what was going wrong which is why I selected his answer as the correct one